# Turning a TSX/JSX React into a string or DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

So I have an unusual requirement from my tech lead. I essentially need to turn a callback that returns JSX and turn the output into an `HTMLElement` or a string.

The thing is that we're building a reusable, low level infinite scroll component that reuses the DOM so that only 20 DOM elements are ever present on the componenent. Here is the codepen for the PoC I was sent for this:

https://codepen.io/hemant30/pen/rNWQEZy?editors=0010

The codepen works, but doesn't handle anything in React, it's purely DOM manipulation.

The callback the component receives is something like this:

```
(data: any) => {
      return (
        <div key={data.id}>
          {data.id} - {data.name}
          <br />
          <a href="#">Text</a>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

The idea is to be able to then, when using this callback internally, turn it into something that can be added to an element through dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

I have tried multiple things and approaches, but my approaches haven't been approved. So I turn to you to see if there is a way to do this or not.

Comment: This is a real "dear god why" ask.  Can you not just convert the whole code to React?

Comment: I'd like to, but apparently this component needs to be very performant and previous attempts at the company weren't as successful in making it both usable and performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) method, it can transform jsx into string html.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <div>
         <Component/>
         /* etc. */
    </div>
);
```